# Spark accumulator, I get always 0 value

Tags: apache-spark

I'm using a LongAccumulator to count the number of record which I save in Cassandra.

```
object Main extends App {
  val conf = args(0)
  val ssc = StreamingContext.getStreamingContext(conf)
  Runner.apply(conf).startJob(ssc)

  StreamingContext.startStreamingContext(ssc)
  StreamingContext.stopStreamingContext(ssc)
}
class Runner (conf: Conf) {
    override def startJob(ssc: StreamingContext): Unit = {
        accTotal = ssc.sparkContext.longAccumulator("total")
        val inputKafka = createDirectStream(ssc, kafkaParams, topicsSet)
        val rddAvro = inputKafka.map{x => x.value()}
        saveToCassandra(rddAvro)
        println("XXX:" + accTotal.value) //-->0
    }


    def saveToCassandra(upserts: DStream[Data]) = {
        val rddCassandraUpsert = upserts.map {
            record =>
            accTotal.add(1)
            println("ACC: " + accTotal.value)  --> 1,2,3,4.. OK. Spark Web UI, ok too.
            DataExt(record.data,
                  record.data1)}
        rddCassandraUpsert.saveToCassandra(keyspace, table)
    }
}
```

I see that the code is executed right and I save data in Cassandra, when I finally print the accumulator the value is 0, but if I print it in the map fuction I can see the right values. Why?

I'm using Spark 2.0.2 and executing from Intellj in local mode.  I have checked the spark web UI and I can see the accumulador updated.

Comment: I added some code. It seems that I have to collect the accumulator value inside and foreachRDD block but outside of the code which it will be executed in the executors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably here:

```
object Main extends App {
   ...
```

Spark [doesn't support applications extending `App`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications), doing so, can result in non-deterministic behaviors:

> Note that applications should define a main() method instead of extending scala.App. Subclasses of scala.App may not work correctly.

You should always use standard applications with `main`:

```
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but it's not that ;)

Comment: @Guille nevertheless that's an may lead to a problem and that's why it's documented.

Comment: Yeah, I changed that too.